# What would the general structure of a reactive-banana game look like?

Tags: haskell, reactive-banana

A simple game that runs its logic every iteration and draws to the screen 60 times per second in an imperative language might look like this:

```
function main() {
    player = new Player()
    lastUpdateTime, lastDrawTime = getTime()
    while (!quit) {
        deltaTime = getTime() - lastUpdateTime
        player.update(deltaTime)
        if (getTime() - lastDrawTime > 1/60) {
            player.draw()
            lastDrawTime = getTime()
        }
        lastUpdateTime = getTime()
    }
    delete player
}
```

I'm just not sure how that translates to reactive-banana.

Comment: BTW: Variable dt isn't good. This will cause accuracy loss in the most of integration schemes.

Comment: I'm new to frp and not sure what you mean by "integration schemes," but as long as it wouldn't cause a difference noticeable to the user, it should be fine for most games.

Comment: Games usually use some sort of 'physics'. Generally speaking, game physics is system of ODEs which are solved by integration. Most of advanced integration schemes require constant dt. But this is a complain on your C code, it isn't related to FRP, so don't mind. In terms of FRP your code falls perfectly within the 'behavior' concept.

Comment: Is your question answered by the answers in ["How to implement a game loop in reactive-banana?"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12685430/403805)?

Comment: @heinrich Kind of, I did however find a [gist](https://github.com/JPMoresmau/TypeClass/blob/master/src/Main.hs) that shows how to use reactive-banana for everything in an SDL game _except_ the actual game logic. So once I get an example working I'll write an answer.